# Macro Producing Run Time Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

My macro is producing a 1004 run time error code. The macro was running correctly yesterday. The issue is happening at the last line of the code here:

```
Windows("Report.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("B3:B10").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Validation_File_" & Format(Date, "dd mm yy") & ".xls").Activate
Sheets("Customer Service").Select
Range("A3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Actuals
'Calls
Range("B3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IF([Report.xlsm]Sheet2!R3C3 =[Template.xlsx]Customer_Service!R2C2,""Correct"",""Incorrect"")"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

three questions:

1. Template.xlsx exist in the same place like yesterday?
2. template.xlsx have sheet Customer_Service ?
3. report.xlsm have Sheet2?

probably answer for one of this question give reason...

Comment: Ah thank you, the template file's tab was changed to Customer Service.